# 15" mid-2015 macbook pro on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 SOME webpages don't load

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, dns, safari

## Some Webpages Won't Load

Hey fam, I just got a new mac (previously a PC user) a few months ago, and I've been having this same issue time and again with the same webpages. It's quite important to me as the webpages I cannot load (on any browser) are essential for my work.

*For reference, I'm sporting a 15" mid-2015 macbook pro on macOS Sierra 10.12.6.*

The problem I feel is a bit more complicated than at first glance, so I'll first outline the symptoms before my own troubleshooting techniques that have yielded no results.

### The inaccessible webpages:

id.heroku.com/    *(The dashboard to the site loads fine, but frustratingly enough, any attempt at the login page results in a ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error message on safari, chrome, and firefox)*

ecowebhosting.co.uk/ *(Any page on this site returns a 403 Forbidden message across all browsers)*

freshprints.herokuapp.com/ *(This is a project I've built through Heroku that I can access and use, however it does not return any results. When tried on any other device, it works fine. Some errors are visible in the JS console and seem to occur when loading jQuery libraries)*

It's important to note that these are all quite accessible to my friends on PCs, Macs, and mobile.
I've been at this problem on and off for months, and I'm at the point where I can't move any further with these projects until I fix this.

### What I've Tried:

#### I've run through [this post](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/520850/some-internet-websites-will-not-load-cant-find-error/) to:

- Set time and date correctly
- Clear firewall settings
- Rebuild network configurations
- Clear certificate management database caches
- Turned off OCSP and CRL services
- Gone through all root certificates to restore default trust settings

#### Then I went on [this forum](https://www.cnet.com/news/cannot-access-secured-web-sites-after-os-x-update/) to:

- Reset browser caches
- Repair permissions through disk utility
- Went through OnyX (titanium-software.fr/en/index.html) and safe boot permissions and rebuilding
- Changing network location and flushing the DNS through the terminal
- Created alternate network locations for Google DNS (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) and Cisco's Open DNS (208.67.222.222, 208.67.222.220) through network preferences

#### Last, I've tried restoring my default httpd.conf and Host files

None of these measures have made any difference to the problems above.
I'm running out of solutions and can't quite find the root cause of these network issues.

If anyone can provide me with information or useful approaches to this problem, it would save me many more hours of frustration.
Thanks!

Comment: If you log into the macOS Guest account (or create a new clean user account on your Mac and log into that) does the problem happen? That would tell us if the problem is with a systemwide config vs a per-user config.

Comment: I don’t see either of those forums telling you to reset HSTS or HPKP settings. In Safari’s preferences, select “Clear all website cookies and data”. This should reset any HTTP security settings those websites told Safari to use. Also, do you have you Mac or your browsers configured to use a proxy?

Comment: @Spiff Just tried both of these suggestions:


Logged into guest on my mac and the problem was the same. Tried again in safe mode as well and there was no noticeable difference, so it must be a global issue.


I then cleared all cookies and data from Safari, then when that didn't work, I selected the HSTS.plist file located in ~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist and deleted it to be sure. No change.

Last, I tried turning off DNS prefetching with the console command: 
defaults write com.apple.safari WebKitDNSPrefetchingEnabled -boolean false. No change. I might try booting Linux.